# Поиск последнего файла в папке на сервере, исходя из имени файла

Tags: файлы, php, файловая-система

Комментарии к статье на сайте хранятся не в БД, а в файлах.

1.txt хранит первые 10 комментов

2.txt следующие 10,

и т.д.

Можно ли как-то получить доступ к последнему файлу (исходя из его имени-номера) из папки? Ведь они необязательно будут расположены по порядку? Если идея для каждого файла применять basename() и математически искать наибольший номер.

Comment: Вы уж простите, но мне кажется, проблема решается совсем не с той стороны.

`dirname` вам ожидаемо вернет имя директории. Вы, видимо, хотели использовать функцию `basename`. 

> Ведь они необязательно будут расположены по порядку?

Есть функция `usort`, есть `sort` + `SORT_NUMERIC` (не знаю, честно говоря, отработает ли). Если хочется жести - можете создифавать файл `def.txt` и писать в нем количество комментариев (и потом реконструировать конкретные названия файлов).

Comment: @Fike, да, изменил вопрос - поспешил. basename. А вот по поводу usort - это да! Подзабыл просто... Проверим!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция scandir() выводит список файлов в папке в виде массива. Второй аргумент указывает, что сортировать надо в обратном порядке.

```
$lastfile = scandir("../..", 1)[0];
```

---

В таком случае можно применить:

```
$files = scandir("./comments_dir");
rsort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);

$lastfile = $files[0];
```

Хотя я бы в таком случае добавлял лидирующие нули к именам файлов

Comment: @mantigatos, это понятно, только где гарантия, что последний файл будет иметь имя с максимальным цифровым basename?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то имена файлов представляют собой возрастающие числа?

Comment: @mantigatos, ну да. В этом и вся фишка.

Comment: > только где гарантия, что последний файл

тогда что вы имеете в виду под "последний файл"?

Comment: @mantigatos, если есть 1.txt, 20.txt, 21.txt, то последний файл - это 21.txt. Просто я не уверен, что 

    $lastfile = scandir("../..", 1)[0];

выдаст именно этот файл

Comment: @Fike, видите как хорошо - теперь и вы и я знаем! Однако, хитрость в алфавитном порядке - может ли такое произойти, что 19.txt будет **ниже** чем например 100.txt? На алфавит надеяться, себя обломать.))

Или 37.txt в алфавите ведь стоит ниже 110.txt!

Comment: Тогда  SORT_NUMERIC   или   SORT_NATURAL (см. обновлённый ответ)

Но всё-же я бы добавил лидирующие нули к именам файлов, будет выглядеть красивее

Comment: На shell

    for i in `ls *.txt`; do  basename $i .txt; done | sort -n | tail -1

Наверное можно вызвать из пхп и прочесть одну строчку (потом добавите .txt и получите искомое имя).